# Exibir um arquivo que está na pasta Storage -- Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou com um problema no meu codigo. Eu consigo inserir normalmente o arquivo dentro da pasta storage

```
$pathfile = $this->path_monografia . $monografia->id . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "monografia.pdf";

Storage::disk('public')->put($pathfile, File::get($request->file('anexo')));

$monografia->caminho = Storage::disk('public')->url($pathfile);
```

Só que ao acessá-la pela view recebo um erro:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="monografia in monografias | startFrom:(currentPage - 1) * pageSize | filter:search | limitTo:pageSize">
                    <td><a href="" ng-href="@{{monografia.caminho}}" > @{{ monografia.titulo }} </a> </td>
                    <td><a href="" ng-href="@{{monografia.caminho}}" > @{{ monografia.autor }} </a> </td>
                    <td><a href="" ng-href="@{{monografia.caminho}}" > @{{ monografia.orientador }} </a> </td>
                    <td><a href="" ng-href="@{{monografia.caminho}}" > @{{ monografia.nivel }} </a> </td>
                    <td><a href="" ng-href="@{{monografia.caminho}}" > @{{ monografia.publicated_at | date:' dd/MM/y' }} </a> </td>
```

Onde monografia.caminho se refere a url que foi salvada no banco de dados. Obrigado desde já

Comment: Voce sabe me dizer qual.o caminho gravado no banco

Comment: /storage/monografias\9\monografia.pdf esse seria um por exemplo. so que o disco public está linkado para app/public na pasta storage

Comment: Se fez o procedimento descrito na documentação? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem